# How do I use Selenium to drag and drop drawing elements into a canvas?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, selenium3

I have an element with an id which I need to select, then drag and drop into a drawing canvas. How do I do this?

The element is outside the canvas and I need to draw it inside the canvas.

```
function createEvent(typeOfEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
    event.initCustomEvent(typeOfEvent, true, true, null);
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {},
        setData: function (key, value) {
            this.data[key] = value;
        },
        getData: function (key) {
            return this.data[key];
        }
    };
    return event;
}
function dispatchEvent(element, event, transferData) {
    if (transferData !== undefined) {
        event.dataTransfer = transferData;
    }
    if (element.dispatchEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
    } else if (element.fireEvent) {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.type, event);
    }
}
function simulateHTML5DragAndDrop(element, target) {
    var dragStartEvent = createEvent('dragstart');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragStartEvent);
    var dropEvent = createEvent('drop');
    dispatchEvent(target, dropEvent, dragStartEvent.dataTransfer);
    var dragEndEvent = createEvent('dragend');
    dispatchEvent(element, dragEndEvent, dropEvent.dataTransfer);
}
```

Comment: See https://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/automated-testing-of-html5-canvas/

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/18254564/631619

Comment: What all have you tried till now? Also go through [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

You can try using Actions for drag and drop actions.

```
Actions dragdrop = new Actions(driver);
WebElement object1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH1"));
WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH2"));
dragdrop.moveToElement(object1).clickandHold();
dragdrop.moveToElement(canvas);
dragdrop.release();
dragdrop.build().perform();
```

You can also use the following code if the above one does not work.

```
Actions dragdrop = new Actions(driver);
WebElement object1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH1"));
WebElement canvas = driver.findElement(By.xpath("XPATH2"));
dragdrop.dragAndDrop(object1, canvas);
dragdrop.build().perform();
```

There is another type of dragandDrop(source, x-offset, y-offset) action which accepts offsets arguments. You may also try using it if these solutions does not work.

Comment: It's not working for me . Actually scenerio is ,I will drag the element to inside the canvas . Element which I am dragging is not a canvas. When I drop it in canvas , itself create image or drawing .

Comment: This too not working, can you help me to work with offset..I think offset will work

Comment: Maybe this question will help in getting the offsets - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21461347/get-the-absolute-position-of-an-element-with-selenium-web-driver